# Wrapper class is not Working

Tags: wrapper-class, quote

Can any one help me on this .I have created a custom visual force page on Quote object which is in PDF foramt.I have written a wrapper class where  values of the opportunity forecast objects is not getting displayed.This "Opportunity Forecast object " is a custom object which is a managed package installation.Is that im making any blunt mistake in the code.Any help is very much appreciated.

**Visual force code :**

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote" 
        applyHtmlTag="false" renderAs="PDF" showheader="false" applyBodyTag="false" extensions="QuoteContentController">



<h2>OpportunityForecast Details</h2>
 <table class="bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0"> Part Numbers</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Quantity</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0"> Price</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0"> Amount</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Quarter</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Actual Price</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <apex:repeat value="{!disp_list}" var="opf">
            <tr>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Product}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Quantity}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Price }"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Amount }"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Quarter }"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.Actual_Price }"/></td>
             </tr>
            </apex:repeat> 
        </tbody>
    </table> 
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Class :**

```
public with sharing class QuoteContentController {

  public Competitor__c com{get;set;}

  public gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c oppf{get;set;}

  public Id qId {get;set;}

//Declare a wrapper class  

  public class Wrapperclass{

 //custom wrapper datatype  

      public string Name{get;set;}  
      public string AccountType{get;set;}  
      public date todaysDate{get;set;}  
      public date Expected_Order_Date{get;set;}
      public string Probability{get;set;}  
      public string Internal_Comment{get;set;}  
      public string External_Comment{get;set;}  

      public string Segment{get;set;}  
      public string Application{get;set;}  
      public string Persona{get;set;}  
      public string Geogrpahy{get;set;}  

      public string PartNumbers{get;set;}  
      public Decimal  Price{get;set;}  
      public Decimal End_Customer_Price{get;set;}  
      public Decimal Quantity {get;set;}  
      public Decimal Total{get;set;}  

      public string RFQ_justification{get;set;}  
      public string Main_Customer_of_Account{get;set;}  
      public string Bridgelux_competition_at_account{get;set;}
      public string Geographic_regions_serviced{get;set;}  
      public string Annual_lighting_revenue{get;set;}  
      public string Annual_LED_revenue_or_percent{get;set;}  
      public string Annual_purchases_of_LED_light_sources{get;set;}
      public string Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB{get;set;}  
      public string Other_information{get;set;}  

      public string Product_Series{get;set;}  
      public string Volume{get;set;} 
      public string Date_Price_is_Valid{get;set;} 

      Public string gmod_Product{get;set;}
      Public Decimal gmod_Quantity{get;set;}
      Public Decimal gmod_Price{get;set;}
      Public Decimal gmod_Quarter{get;set;}
      Public Decimal gmod_Month{get;set;}
      Public Decimal gmod_Amount{get;set;}
      Public Decimal Actual_Price{get;set;}
      Public Decimal  gmod_Year{get;set;}
      public wrapperClass(){} 

  }

    public QuoteContentController(){}

    public QuoteContentController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

      qId=Apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('Id');

    }

     public List<wrapperClass> disp_list {get;set;}{
    //define constructor to instantiate the wrapper data type 

      disp_list=new list<wrapperclass>();

    //Query all the list 

    list<Quote> q =[select id ,Name ,Effective_Date__c ,Comments__c ,
                    Quote.Opportunity.Probability ,Quote.Opportunity.AccSegment__c ,Quote.Opportunity.AccApplication__c,Quote.Opportunity.Persona__c,Quote.Opportunity.Region__c
                    from Quote where id=:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')];

    list<QuoteLineItem> qli =[Select QuoteId , PricebookEntry.Product2.Name ,Unitprice ,End_Customer_Price__c ,Quantity , TotalPrice from QuoteLineItem where QuoteId =:qId ];

    list<Account> a = [Select id ,Name ,Main_Customers_of_Account__c ,Bridgelux_Competition_at_Account__c,Servicing_Region__c ,
                      Annual_LED_Revenue__c,Annual_Purchases_of_LED_Sources_SAM__c ,Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB__c from Account where account.id =:qId ];

   list<Competitor__c>  com = [Select id ,Part_Number__c,Product_Series__c,Price_Offered__c,Volume__c,Date_Price_is_Valid__c from Competitor__c ]  ; 

  // list<gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c>  opflist = [Select id ,Name ,gmod__Product__c,gmod__Quantity__c,gmod__Price__c ,   gmod__Quarter__c ,gmod__Amount__c ,Actual_Price__c from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c   ];

    list<gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c>  opflist = [Select id ,Name ,gmod__Product__c,gmod__Quantity__c,gmod__Price__c , gmod__Month__c,  gmod__Quarter__c ,gmod__Amount__c ,Actual_Price__c ,gmod__Year__c from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c  where createddate!=null order by name limit 1 ]; 

       //Iterate through each list to extract the values and add it to the custom wrapper data type  

         for (Quote qt :q){

            for(integer i=0;i<opflist.size();i++){

                //Instantiating the wrapper SObject 

                wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();

  //Assigning the wrapper variables from the SObject Fields in the database. 

  w.gmod_Product = opflist[i].gmod__Product__c;

  w.gmod_Quantity =opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;

  w.gmod_Price=opflist[i].gmod__Price__c;

  w.Name =opflist[i].Name;

  w.gmod_Quarter=opflist[i].gmod__Quarter__c;

  w.gmod_Month=opflist[i].gmod__Month__c;

  w.gmod_Amount=opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c;

  w.Actual_Price=opflist[i].Actual_Price__c;

  w.gmod_Year=opflist[i].gmod__Year__c;

      //Adding everthing to the List  


     w.name =qt.name;

      disp_list.add(w);


       }
     }
   }  
 } //End of Class
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting or the behaviour you are expecting and you it's not happening

Comment: Can you narrow down to the more relevant code?  I feel like we don't need to see your entire visualforce page.  Also, can you confirm there is data there in **disp_list**?  It doesn't look like you made any effort to put debugs into your code yet.

Comment: @MihaiNeagoe:The "Opportunity forecast values" are not getting displayed in the vf page.

Comment: @dphil:I have cut down the code.The disp_list  data is not getting dispalyed in the vf page.On "Opportunity Forecast" object their is visual force page created.Now that vf page data should get displayed in my vf page which is in PDF format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the code from method:

```
public QuoteContentController(){
```

into the method

```
public QuoteContentController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
```

Currently the code from the no parameter method will never be executed

Comment: :Can u help me out where i need to make changes in the code.

Comment: Have you done what was suggested in my answer?

Comment: :I have made changes as u have suggested.

Comment: :I have updated the code with necessary changes.I get the Opportunity forecast details, but it does not display the current detail page details and in place of product name i get the Product Id displayed.Is that im making any mistake in the SOQl Query.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the "current details page" also,  your query for good_Product__c may only get you the ID. You may need to query through the relationship to get the name

Comment: :I get the opportunity forecast details displayed in PDF ,but which is not related to the present record.